# Create new class with init

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create new class by `type` function.

```
def create_fk_widget_from_model(model, **kwargs):
    to_field = kwargs.pop('to_field', 'id')
    rel = ManyToOneRel(None, model, to_field)  # type: ignore
    return type(
        f'{model.__name__}ForeignKeyRawIdWidget',
        (ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, ),
        {'__init__': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.__init__(
            rel=rel,
            admin_site=admin.site)}
    )
```

But there is a problem. I need to change `__init__` in new class, how to do it?

Comment: By passing something different to `'__init__':`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, my variant isn't working, i need to pass my ```rel``` in ```__init__```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
def create_fk_widget_from_model(model, **kwargs):
    to_field = kwargs.pop('to_field', 'id')
    rel = ManyToOneRel(None, model, to_field)  # type: ignore
    def __init__(self):
        return ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.__init__(self, rel=rel, admin_site=admin.site)
    
    return type(
        f'{model.__name__}ForeignKeyRawIdWidget',
        (ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, ),
        {'__init__': __init__}
    )
```